# How to populate Hive Table with all timestamps(86400) in a day

Tags: hadoop, hive, timestamp, hdfs, hiveql

I want a Hive Table with 4 Columns `<date,key,Timestamp,count>`. Here Keys can be multiple count should be numeric 0. I need a records for every second in the day for each key. 
E.g. I have 2 Keys A and B. I want 86400 Records for each key in the table. From `00:00:00 till 23:59:59`

I know about current_timestamp function. Not sure whether it will fit here.

```
Date, Key, Timestamp, Count
2019-05-31, A, 00:00:00, 0
2019-05-31, A, 00:00:01, 0
2019-05-31, A, 00:00:02, 0
.
.
.
2019-05-31, A, 23:59:59, 0
2019-05-31, B, 00:00:00, 0
2019-05-31, B, 00:00:01, 0
2019-05-31, B, 00:00:02, 0
.
.
.
2019-05-31, B, 23:59:59, 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query will produce timestamps required:

```
 select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2019-05-31 00:00:00')+i) as ts 
   from (select 
               posexplode(split(space(86399),' ')) as (i,x)
        )s
```

Explanation:

Subquery s generates rows with seconds. If you join with such subquery, for example using cross join (it depends on your initial dataset) you will get each row duplicated 86400 times

`space(86399)` - produces string of 86399 spaces
`split()` - produces array spaces
`posexplode` - explodes array and produces a table of position and element.
Position(i) is in the range 0 - 86399, we will use it as seconds to add to start timestamp

`unix_timestamp('2019-05-31 00:00:00')` - this gives start timestamp in seconds passed from unix epoch. We are adding seconds (i) to it and converting again to timestamp, in such way we get 1 second incremented timestamp for each row.

Join with it and if you need date and time separately, use substring.

Demo:

For example your initial table contains two rows with timestamps and two keys A and B, you can join it with seconds generating subquery:

```
with your_table as( --This is initial data example
select stack(2,
'2019-05-31 00:00:00', 'A', 
'2019-05-31 00:00:00', 'B'
) as (ts, Key)
)

select min(ts), max(ts), key --aggregated result for the demo
from
(
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(t.ts)+i) as ts , t.key
  from your_table t
      cross join (select posexplode(split(space(86399),' ')) as (i,x))s
)s group by key
```

Result (aggregation added, because it generates too many rows):

```
min                 max                 key
2019-05-31 00:00:00 2019-05-31 23:59:59 B
2019-05-31 00:00:00 2019-05-31 23:59:59 A
```